# What is the most resource-efficient way to transfer power over long distances?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

What is the most resource-efficient way to transfer power over long distances?  I want to power my quarry with ic2 solar arrays back in my base.

Comment: With the tag minecraft-tekkit I assume you mean you have the actual modpack "Tekkit" installed (just asking, some people might think it's enough to say they use the tekkit launcher)

Comment: tekkit-lite modpack, actually

Comment: Ok, my answer isn't really different with tekkit-lite, the necessary mods seem to be available there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Tekkit pack doesn't seem to include Mekanism and its generators (if I'm not mistaken), Thermal Expansion appears to be the best way.

What worked for me best and what was the easiest way to move my quarry after use was to use Tesseracts and Electrical Engines. While Electrical Engines have a bit of a conversion loss, they still work quite efficiently. Use however many Engines you can power and push that energy directly into the tesseract, and set the tesseract directly next to the quarry.

If there is a more resource efficient way, I don't know it.

**Edit:** As Tekkit-Lite doesn't seem to have the Electrical Engines, you can use an "Energy Link", which might even be more efficient. It should be in the PowerConverters Mod that's included in Lite, try to look that up [here](http://tekkitclassic.wikia.com/wiki/Energy_Link). I do not know if that takes up more energy than the opposing side needs, but I doubt it. However, a Quarry uses really a lot of energy, so sometimes it might seem like it needs too much. You should just test it out, maybe with an EU reader or something similar.

Comment: I think they removed the electrical engines. If i use power converters and a tesseract will that drain my ic2 power completely or just enough to power the quarry?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps.